# Request.Querystring after URL rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there an easy way to get the value of a Querystring after it has been rewritten to a nice looking url? (URL REWRITE)

For example:

```
www.example.com/Home?CatId=Shoes
```

Here I can use request.querystring which I can use to get data from the database.

```
www.example.com/shoes
```

But here I can't do that...

Comment: But how can I get the ''shoes'' value out of the link, like I get values with querystring?

Comment: Same way, on the page Request.Querystring("CatId")

Answer (score 0):

You can install url re-writer module on IIS 7.0 and then do the following within web.config to create friendly urls:

```
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="CatsMaps">
                <add key="www.example.com/Home?CatId=Shoes" value="/shoes" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
```

And if you have all URL's stored in database then look into DBProvider:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate the rewrite map(s) and check each value but you could get more than one match obviously.